# Zend Framework: How to pass data from bootstrap to layout?

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping

I have some configuration values set in application.ini and i want to pass those values to the layout on application load. How can i do this from bootstrap ? For trial i tried doing this

In my Bootstrap initialization function:

```
$this->bootstrap('view');
$view = $this->getResource('view');
$view->layout()->whatever = "Some Value";
```

In layout:

```
<?php echo $this->layout()->whatever; ?>
```

But m not able to get the value to display in the layout.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
$this->bootstrap('view');
$view = $this->getResource('view');
$view->whatever = 'Some value';
```

Then, in layout:

```
<?php echo $this->whatever ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to grab the Layout and from there the view object:

```
$this->bootstrap('layout');
$layout = $this->getResource('layout');
$view = $layout->getView();
$view->text = 'Welcome';
```